# List all files from WhatsApp documents folder android 12 programmatically

Tags: android, whatsapp

Here I am trying to get pdf and csv files from WhatsApp Documents folder but not getting any instead of printing only Sent and Private folders only but I want all files from WhatsApp Documents
Please help

```
File srcFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Android/media/"+"com.whatsapp" + "/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Documents/");

File[] allFiles = srcFile.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
   @Override
   public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
      System.out.println("filename="+filename);
      return (filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf") && filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv"));
   }
});
```

list all files from WhatsApp Documents folder

Comment: On an Android 11+ device an app can see all the directories and subdirectories there are on external storage. But not the files in them if the files are not created by the app itself. (except some media files ). Well ... not with classic file means.

Comment: @blackapps I can access WhatsApp Images , audio and video folder files but for documents folder its not listing any file

Comment: Well that is exactly what i said isnt it!? Please read better.